How to filter out orders with zero dollars in sales in SQL?
I'm trying to filter out orders that have $0 in sales but I'm somewhat new to writing SQL code so I'm not exactly sure how I would go about writing this. I'm more familiar with writing DAX, which in this case would look like this:
=CALCULATE( SUM( 'Order Detail'[Net Sales] ),
FILTER( 'Order Detail', 'Order Detail'[Net Sales]<>0 ) )

I use this same formula for the other variables as well (i.e. commission, quantity sold, etc)
=CALCULATE( SUM( 'Order Detail'[Commission Amount] ),
FILTER( 'Order Detail', 'Order Detail'[Net Sales]<>0 ) )

How could I write this in SQL code? So far, here is what I have (see below) -- which it does calculate everything I am wanting it to; however, it does not exclude those orders where an item has $0 in sales.
For further context, an item is sometimes given away for free, which on the order details it will still record the quantity "sold" but show as having $0 in sales. And so when I'm trying to determine an accurate depiction of an item's sales/profit, I do not want to include those orders where the sales were $0; which I would also need to extend that filter to all the other order detail variables as well (i.e. exclude quantity/commission/GP/GPAC when an order has $0 in sales)
SELECT
[Item Number]
,SUM( od.[Net Sales] ) as "Net Sales"
,SUM( od.[Quantity Shipped] ) as "Quantity"
,SUM( od.[Commission Amount]) as "Commission"
,SUM( op.[GP] ) as "GP"
,SUM( op.[GPAC] ) as "GPAC"

FROM [ORDERS] as "o"
INNER JOIN [ORDER DETAIL] as "od" on o.[Order ID] = od.[Order Id]
INNER JOIN [Order Detail Profit] as "op" on od.[Order Detail ID] = op.[Order Detail ID]
INNER JOIN [CUSTOMER] as "c" on c.[Customer ID] = o.[Customer ID]
WHERE DATEDIFF( MM, [INVOICE DATE], GETDATE() ) <= 12
AND [Account Type] = 'REGULAR'
GROUP BY [Item Number]
ORDER BY [Item Number]

I tried adding:
WHERE od.[Net Sales] <> 0

But it doesn't appear to filter out quantity, commission, GP, and GPAC for an order when the net sales are $0.
Essentially I just want to exclude orders that have $0 in sales.
I hope what I wrote makes sense -- any help would be much appreciated! Thanks

Perhaps you want a HAVING clause?

Do you want to exclude individual lines (order detail) where sales is 0, or entire orders?

A [mcve] would make this much easier to get.

Run this and see what you get. Once with the comment and then without:
SELECT
[Item Number]
,od.[Net Sales] as "Net Sales"
,od.[Quantity Shipped] as "Quantity"
,od.[Commission Amount] as "Commission"
,op.[GP] as "GP"
,op.[GPAC] as "GPAC"
FROM [ORDERS] as "o"
INNER JOIN [ORDER DETAIL] as "od" on o.[Order ID] = od.[Order Id]
INNER JOIN [Order Detail Profit] as "op" on od.[Order Detail ID] = op.[Order Detail ID]
INNER JOIN [CUSTOMER] as "c" on c.[Customer ID] = o.[Customer ID]
WHERE DATEDIFF( MM, [INVOICE DATE], GETDATE() ) <= 12
AND [Account Type] = 'REGULAR'
--AND od.[Net Sales] <> 0
ORDER BY 2, 1

